# Do Microsoft Access backup files have a proprietary format?

Tags: linux, ms-access, mdbtools

A client of mine somehow had his site lost/hacked/destroyed by gnomes and I have the "fun" job of restoring it for him from a backup. It uses a combination of ColdFusion and Microsoft Access (yuck!). I set up a Railo server on my computer, however it cannot use Microsoft Access .mdb files out of the box. I then tried using mdbtools to convert the database files to a usable format. It worked fine for a .mdb file, however one of the files has the file extension .BAK, which I'm assuming is some sort of proprietary Microsoft Access backup thing.

So my question is: Does anyone know if there is a way to convert a Microsoft Access .BAK file to an .mdb file? I obviously tried renaming it with no effect.

> $ mdb-tables tradelionNew_db_200710080307.BAK
>   Couldn't open database.

Another question, could this error message be due to the file being password protected?

More information: I opened the file up with a text editor and the first line has the word `TAPE` right at the beginning and then a bunch of random (binary) characters. The .mdb file has the words `Standard Jet DB`. I believe this is part of the file header to indicate the file type. Also, in the .BAK file, a lot of the content was actually available in plain text, so if the file is password protected, Microsoft sure did a bad job at protecting it.

Comment: There is no backup format for Access/Jet/ACE files, so I think what you're seeing isn't an Access file at all. It must be some backup format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the .bak isn't just an SQL Server backup file?  They appear to start with TAPE.

Comment: You could very well be right. Any idea how I can tell? I'm on linux.

Comment: I think you'll need to find a windows PC (can't be that hard right?)... just install SQL Server Express (free edition).